# Save variable number of answers to single textbox with Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JS and I am not yet familiar with internal workings. Can someone point out the error in my thinking?

The basic idea is to ask a complex question, construct the answer with JS (to a CSV syntax) and feed it to a textbox. (From here it will be processed to a db.) Example included below: How many children do you have? What is their names and age?

Perhaps, the new element generated by the first button is not added to the document? How to do this, or how to address the value in it?

How can I make the values submitted to previous lines stick in the event of adding a new line. For example `'Jack'` and `'10'` is written to the first line, the user pressed the add new line, than this information should stay in the first line.

Incorrectly working example: The save button stops working if the code in the loop is added.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>How many children do you have? What is their names and age?</p>
        <input type="text" id="qchildren" />
        <div id="qchildren-answer-wrapper"></div>

        <button type="button" onclick="addNew()">Add new entry</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="save()">Save</button>
        <script>
        var lines = 0;

        function addNew() {
            lines++;
            document.getElementById("qchildren-answer-wrapper").innerHTML += 'Gyermek neve:<input type="text" id="qchildrenname' + window.lines + '" /> Gyermek eletkora:<input type="text" id="qchildrenage' + window.lines + '" /><br/>';
        }

        function save() {
            var answer = '';
            for (var ii = 0; ii < window.lines; ii++) {
                answer += document.getElementById('qchildrenname' + ii.toString()).value.toString() + ',' + document.getElementById('qchildrenage' + ii.toString()).value.toString() + ';';
            }
            document.getElementById("qchildren").value = answer;
        }
        < /script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of using multiple `input` elements to add extra lines, use a `textarea` element.

Comment: My task is more complex. It might be necessary to use dropdown boxes, date choosers, etc. The user can not be prompted to construct correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=Below code should work (AddNew function changed):

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<p>How many children do you have? What is their names and age?</p>
 <input type="text" id="qchildren" />
 <div id="qchildren-answer-wrapper"></div>



<button type="button" onclick="addNew()">Add new entry</button>
<button type="button" onclick="save()">Save</button>

<script>
var lines=0;
function addNew()
{
lines++;
var newElement = document.createElement("span");
  newElement.innerHTML =  'Gyermek neve:<input type="text" id="qchildrenname'+window.lines+'" /> Gyermek eletkora:<input type="text" id="qchildrenage'+window.lines+'" /><br/>';
document.getElementById("qchildren-answer-wrapper").appendChild(newElement);
}

function save()
{
var answer='';
for (var ii=1;ii<=window.lines;ii++)
{ 
answer+=document.getElementById('qchildrenname'+ii.toString()).value.toString()+','+document.getElementById('qchildrenage'+ii.toString()).value.toString()+';';
}
document.getElementById("qchildren").value=answer;
}
</script>


</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves the data sticking at adding a new line. Save still doesn't work.

Comment: Adjusted the code for save as well.  Need to start at 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try code like this:

```
function addNew()
{
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'Gyermek neve:<input type="text" id="qchildrenname'+window.lines+'" /> Gyermek eletkora:<input type="text" id="qchildrenage'+window.lines+'" /><br/>';
document.getElementById("qchildren-answer-wrapper").appendChild(div );
lines++;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JByVg/8/

What happens in your case is that all previously created elements are recreated again because `element.innerHTML += "some_html"` is equal to `element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + "some_html"` or, more clear, I suppose, `var oldHtml = element.innerHTML;element.innerHTML = ""; element.innerHTML = oldHtml + "some_html"`

Browser does not populate value="..." entered by user when you do `var oldHtml = element.innerHTML` and after `+=` you have old elements recreated without values entered by user. At the same time, appendChild does not recreate old elements.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/JByVg/4/) example demonstrates how `.innerHTML` returns only initial HTML (I've added value="test" to your `qchildrenname` element code)

Comment: Thanks, that solves the data sticking at adding a new line. Save still doesn't work.

Comment: See updated answer. I've moved lines++ at the end of `addNew`

Comment: When you add new items, you start with 1 (because lines is incremented before you use it), but when you try to collect values - you start with 0